# Fading the body using javascript

Tags: javascript

As it is clear from the title of my question that i want to fade body using javascript.
in short what i want to do is i want to display an alert box in the screen and other than alert box whole body background will be fade.Is it possible using javascript?

**What i tried so far:**

HTML:

```
<tr><td><table class="popup" style="font-size:12px;border-bottom:1px solid #482C1F !important; text-align: center !important;top:-10000px;position:absolute;" id="nameFieldPopup" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

  <div id="dontfade">  
<tr><td align="left" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:30px; " id="detailstd"></td></tr>
<tr><td align="right"><input type="button" name="ok" value="OK" onClick="closepopup();"></td></tr>
    </table></td></tr>
</tr>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    window.onload=function(){
    moduleidvar=<?php echo $moduleid?>;
    alert(moduleidvar);
    if (moduleidvar==-1) {
     var tdControl = document.getElementById("detailstd");
     tdControl.innerHTML = "eNPS is een moderne
     en efficiënte manier voor het meten van medewerker bevlogenheid.In een  ";

    document.getElementById('nameFieldPopup').style.top="";
    document.getElementById('nameFieldPopup').style.visibility = "visible";  
    }

    };
```

Comment: Try `document.body.style.opacity = '0.3'` when the alert box is shown. Reset the value to 1 later

Comment: @tewathia thanks for the reply but what i want is in any case when the alert box is displayed the body should be fade.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want the body to slowly fade out as the alert box pops out? Try `document.body.style.opacity = 1; var h = setInterval(function(){if(document.body.style.opacity>0.3) {document.body.style.opacity-=0.1;} else {clearInterval(h);}}, 100)`

Comment: @tewathia thanks again for the reply :) what i want is when the alert box is popped up other than the alert box everything is fade out.

Comment: Umm, see my answer. I've posted a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/R6tWc/3/)

I'm slowly reducing the opacity of one `div`(which can contain all your background stuff) while the other `div`(which can contain the stuff that isn't supposed to fade) remains unaltered.

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {
    fade.style.opacity = 1;
    var h = setInterval(function () {
        if (fade.style.opacity > 0.3) {
            fade.style.opacity -= 0.1;            
        } else {
            clearInterval(h);
            alert('some text');
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Edit: Updating the fiddle for the second part of your question.

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/R6tWc/4/)

(this is in jQuery though)

Comment: i will accept it but one last question suppose my table row contents which i dont want to fade is inside the div which i want to fade out than how i will handle this situation?

Comment: You'll have to give the table(that you don't want to fade) a different class and then skip it while reducing the opacity. Something like `document.querySelectorAll('#fade *:not(.noFade)')`. And then in the onclick function parse through each of the elements selected.

Comment: @RishabhRaj Fixed. See the second link in my answer

Answer (score 3):

A common technique to fade the body is to use a `div` which is on top of everything except your popup. When you fade in/out this div it looks like the body is fading.

In my Fiddle, the popup has a higher z-index than the white mask. When you click on the popup it will fadeout the mask so the body will be visible:

```
$("#popup").click(function() {
    $("#mask").fadeOut();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

The mask is created with:

```
#mask {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

The `opacity: 0.9` makes the mask semi-transparent. You can change this to any value between 1 and 0.

See http://jsfiddle.net/WaPXN/1/

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not what i want ,what i want is when the alert box is displayed the body should get fade and only alert box is visible.

Comment: with fade you mean half transparent?

Comment: I updated the example by adding opacity: 0.9 to the css

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you just want a modal dialog. This can be done easily with jQuery UI. It won't be blocking like a regular alert().

```
<script>
var showAlert = function() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                // Your code here
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
};
$(function() {
    showAlert();
});
```

```
<body>
    <div>background</div>
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Alert">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</body>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5kyZQ/)